# Azure and Javascript application caching

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, browser-cache, azure-caching

I have an Angular application that I'm deploying to Azure. Many times I find myself having to clear the cache in my browser to see new changes, sometimes it might not even work and I'd have to wait.

The Javascript bundle file name changes every time I deploy something, so I think that shouldn't be the reason. But what could be the reason? Maybe Azure is caching my app?

Comment: How are you versioning your file?

Comment: @MarkC. when i push to github it deploys automatically and creates a js file with the  commit  number appended. Something like "/app.7c0e8e3308bc08816199.js"

Comment: Append a version parameter to avoid client side caching, e.g. `/app.js?v=hAsH`. Also, webpack is built for local debugging, not remote. There's one additional trick in Chrome to quickly clear the cache, open Dev Tools, rightclick on the page reload icon and pick `Empty cache and hard reload`.