# Azure App Configuration client library - caching of getConfigurationSetting

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, azure-app-configuration

I'm using the library @azure/app-configuration in my Angular web site and it works great. I used it for feature flagging.
I run into the issue, that when I change a feature flag state (enabled to disabled or vice versa), this is not reflected in the website.

When I check the Network tab, I can see a request, but its status is "from disk cache".
[image: request in network tab]
In the response headers, I don't see any cache control headers, but I do see a LastModified header. It seems that this may impact caching.

I can't find any option or setting in the AppConfigurationClient or the method `getConfigurationSetting` to disable caching or refresh. I tried the option "acceptDateTime" set to `new Date()` but that doesn't make any difference. Also been playing around with other options, no luck

Alternatively, would it be possible to clear the cache for this URL (https://{{name}}.azconfig.io)?

Comment: [Azure and Javascript application caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584752/azure-and-javascript-application-caching) and [Azure getConfigurationSetting to retrieve Azure feature flags - client side](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/22340)

Comment: Thanks @DeepDave-MT Based on the second post, I've switched to a server side model. I.e. now my API connects to Azure App Configuration and I've implemented IMemoryCache.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment above, [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/22340) describes that the library is not recommended for client side use. I agree, as I wasn't already very happy about exposing such a connection string in JS. So I've moved the logic to my API, implemented IMemoryCache, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is still looking for a fix, adding cache-control header worked for me.

```
const setting = await client?.getConfigurationSetting(
   { key: 'keyname' },
   { requestOptions: { customHeaders: { 'cache-control': 'no-cache' } } }
);
```